# How to Interpolate vectors in Python?

Tags: python

How to interpolate vector between 2 vectors in blender-python?
I hope you get my question.
Example:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [mathutils.Vector](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils.vector#mathutils.Vector):

1. [Vector.lerp](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils.vector#mathutils.Vector.lerp) for linear interpolation.
2. [Vector.slerp](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils.vector#mathutils.Vector.lerp) for spherical interpolation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

```
c = a.lerp(b, 0.0)
# c == a
c = a.lerp(b, 0.5)
# c == (a + b) / 2
c = a.lerp(b, 1.0)
# c == b
```

Comment: i think you mean C == B in your third example

Answer (score 7):

```
from mathutils import Vector

v = Vector((0,1,2))
v.negate()
print(v)
# <Vector (-0.0000, -1.0000, -2.0000)>

def interpolate(t, vector_a, vector_b):
# t is from interval <0, 1>
    return (1 - t) * vector_a + t * vector_b
```