# Python: mix/interpolate values

Tags: python

How to mix/interpolate values in blender-python? I tried to google but i did not find the answer.

In Java, C, GLSL there are some methods which do it:

```
val3 = mix(val1, val2, mix_val)
# or
val3 = interpolate(val1, val2, mix_val)
```

1) How mix two float values? Example:

```
val1 = 10.0
val2 = 0.0
mix_val = 0.5
```

2) How to interpolate float values of two arrays? Example:

```
array_val1 = [10.0, 2.5, 3.0]
array_val2 = [0.0, 12.0, 75.0]
mix_val = 0.5
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you simply put the values into a vector as in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19595/how-to-interpolate-vectors-in-python

Comment: Numpy supports this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224970/array-interpolation-in-python

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a generic python question, not specific to Blender. This may be better suited to a specific python SE.

Comment: This is called linear interpolation.  There is a document I can think of that mentions it called the 'CG Tutorial' published by nVidia.  The accompanying source code is called the CG Toolkit.  The formula is "result = A * (1-mixFactor) + B * mixFactor