# What is the C# Mathf.Lerp equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, mathematics

I have a basic menu script with a slider. The idea is that the slider will control the rotation of a bone. That bone will then rotate the object. I worked out the exact euler angles to rotate it by, and now I'm a little bit stuck. I've used C# for quite some time and C# has this thing called [Mathf.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html), and I wondered if there is a python equivalent? If so, what is it?

Here is what I'm aiming for:

```
elif origin == 'screen_rotation':
    bones = bpy.context.object.pose.bones

    Mathf.Lerp(bones["Screen"].rotation_euler[1] = 0, bones["Screen"].rotation_euler[1] = 1.58825, screen_rotation)
```

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19595/599

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lerp typically means linear interpolation.

Assume A, B, C are floating point values.

Assume C is in the range [0.0, 1.0]

lerp(A, B, C) might be implemented as

value = (C * A) + ((1-C) * B) // convex combination

When C equals 0 value equals B.

When C equals 1 value equals A.

When C equals .5 value equals the average of A and B.

Of course you can switch the factors (C) and (1-C) depending on your desired implementation.  You can also switch A and B depending on your desired implementation.

Comment: Ok, so is this right? bones["Screen"].rotation_euler[1] = (self.screen_rotation * 0) + ((1 - self.screen_rotation) * 1.58825)

Comment: Ok, it works, but only when the bone is selected and in pose mode...

Answer (score 5):

The Blender python API provides the equivalent functions for linear interpolation [(Lerp)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation):

- [Vectors.lerp](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html?highlight=lerp#mathutils.Vector.lerp)
- [Matrix.lerp](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html?highlight=lerp#mathutils.Matrix.lerp)

The quaternion alternative of euler angles requires [spherical lerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp)

- [Quaternion.slerp](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html?highlight=lerp#mathutils.Quaternion.slerp)